# bash workflow for operating with big number of tar.gz archives

Tags: bash, tar

I am working with the directory consisted of 4 sub-dirrectories

```
ls -t
pnmrnp40_to_69  pnmrnp9028_to_9100  pnmrnp00_to_39  pnmrnp70_to_9028
```

inside of each prmnp* subdir there are many filles belonged either to *.tar.gz archive or *.md5sub (which I don not know what is it so it should be removed).

```
charlie@Precision-7920-Tower:~/Documents/script/mega_data/pnmrnp/pnmrnp40_to_69$ ls -t
ligands57_dir_results.tar.gz.md5sum  ligands40_dir_results.tar.gz.md5sum
ligands57_dir_results.tar.gz         ligands69_dir_results.tar.gz
ligands69_dir_results.tar.gz.md5sum  ligands68_dir_results.tar.gz
ligands68_dir_results.tar.gz.md5sum  ligands67_dir_results.tar.gz
ligands67_dir_results.tar.gz.md5sum  ligands66_dir_results.tar.gz
ligands66_dir_results.tar.gz.md5sum  ligands65_dir_results.tar.gz
```

I need a simple bash workflow which will move to each of the subdirectories

1. remove all *.md5sub
2. untar all *.tar.gz to the same subfolder (keeping the name of the original archive).

Here is my workflow in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
# assuming that the script is in the folder contained all subdirectories
dir="$PWD"

# loop each subdirectory
for subdir in ${dir}
cd ${subdir}
# unzip each archive to the same place
for tar in *.tar.gz; do
tar xzvf $tar
done
# return to initial dir
cd ..
done
```

are there any possibilities to make this script more efficient in order that it could be adapted for very big number of archives?

Comment: Why don't you just use `find`? (with `realpath` and `dirname`, in case it has no facilities for `cd` part)

Comment: Did you run your code? Your loop `for subdir in ${dir}` iterates over one directory (the current working directory) only and would even split it in words if the directory name would contain a space. Please show the example location of a `*.tar.gz` file in a nested subdirectory and where you want to get the unpacked contents. What do you want to happen if the archive contains absolute paths?

Comment: yes indeed it would be interesting to try using find. I've just updated my first topic indicating containt of each of the subfolders (there are 4 subfolders with the same data organization). So I need to untar each of the archives to the same initial place where it is ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find(1)`:

```
...
       -execdir command ;

       -execdir command {} +
              Like -exec, but the specified command is run from the
              subdirectory containing the matched file, which is not normally
              the directory in which you started find.  As with -exec, the {}
              should be quoted if find is being invoked from a shell.  This a
              much more secure method for invoking commands, as it avoids race
              conditions during resolution of the paths to the matched files.
              As with the -exec action, the `+' form of -execdir will build a
              command line to process more than one matched file, but any
              given invocation of command will only list files that exist in
              the same subdirectory.  If you use this option, you must ensure
              that your $PATH environment variable does not reference `.';
              otherwise, an attacker can run any commands they like by leaving
              an appropriately-named file in a directory in which you will run
              -execdir.  The same applies to having entries in $PATH which are
              empty or which are not absolute directory names.  If any
              invocation with the `+' form returns a non-zero value as exit
              status, then find returns a non-zero exit status.  If find
              encounters an error, this can sometimes cause an immediate exit,
              so some pending commands may not be run at all.  The result of
              the action depends on whether the + or the ; variant is being
              used; -execdir command {} + always returns true, while
              -execdir command {} ; returns true only if command returns 0.
...
```

```
find -type f -name '*.tar.gz' -execdir tar xvf {} \;
```

Comment: thanks!! could you specify if I need to execute this commande inside of each subfolders (so I have to put this command inside of my for loop) or I can do it one time being in the directory contained 4 subfolders ??

Comment: No, you can use that once you `cd` into the *lowest level* directory that consists of *all* the files of concern (that is, in your case, `the directory contained 4 subfolders [sic.]`) The reason is, `find` is recursive by default.

Comment: top! may you specify is it possible to use it in the same way to remove absolutely all filles with a given extension? find -type f -name '*.md5sum -execdir rm\; or something like this ?

Comment: `find` has its own `-delete` switch. You don't even need `-exec`/`-execdir`/`rm` for that.

Comment: As a tip, you may want to check the the list of files to process / delete before actually performing any action with the corresponding switch, in case you are still in e.g. `$HOME` (because you forget to `cd` to the right directory). In case it's long, you can pipe the output to a pager, e.g.`| less`.

Comment: top, molto grazie!

Comment: I guess in your example there was small typo, since this should be find -type f -name *.tar.gz -execdir tar xvf {} \;    (without single quote near the name of the archive ...) one more question: i've just found that execution of this command creates a folder for each archive within each of the subfolder. So in the case of many archives we shall have many sub-sub-folders etc. is it rather possible to extract all of the contains directly to the subfolder (so as the end it should simply consist of the mix of all extracted filles)?

Comment: Not really. Although I'm not sure if there's actually any case in which there will be problem when the quotes are not used, but the intention is that the `*` is for `find` but not the shell (to expand / glob). I don't think the *directories* are created by `find`. Rather they are contents of the tarballs. (In that case you may see the `--strip-components=` option of `tar`.)

Comment: I mean the problem in your case was in only ONE single quite. probably it should be find -type f -name '*.tar.gz' -execdir tar xvf {} \; shouldn't it ?

Comment: Oh right. Just fixed it.

Comment: grazie mille! A presto!